# Lazily Initialize/Load a GXT Widget When Its Parent Becomes Visible

Tags: gwt, applet, lazy-loading, gxt, gwtp

I am very new to GXT (and GWT/GWTP for that matter). I want to know if I can lazily load a GXT (4.0) [custom] widget when a modal Dialog that contains its panel is displayed (dialog initially not shown and only appears when a button is clicked).

The reason I want this behavior is that this widget needs to load an applet HTML code which is not available when the page initially instantiates all the other field widgets/panels/dialogs. Therefore, I need to delay obtaining the applet code from another application until the dialog is explicitly appears.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, lazy loading is possible. For example the IFrameElement has a LoadHandler event. Other widgets will also have events which you can tag on to.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading of images and urls loaded into a GWT Frame (IFrameElement). You can catch the event once say the image/url is loaded using the LoadHandler event.

```
private void loadLoginPage() {
    final Frame frame = new Frame(url_base + url_login); // set the frames url
    frame.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
            // Get the document from the loaded frame (similar to RootPanel on main page)
            Document doc = IFrameElement.as(frame.getElement()).getContentDocument();

            // From here you can wrap widgets in the frame like this

            final TextBox username = TextBox.wrap(doc.getElementById("username")); // from the html doc using id="username"

            // grab a div element

            DivElement div = DivElement.as(doc.getElementById("mydiv"));

            // Create content to be added to the doc

            ButtonElement button_elem = doc.createPushButtonElement();
            Button button = Button.wrap(button_elem);

            // attach to the document

            div.appendChild(button.getElement());
        }
    });
    // Attach to DOM
    RootPanel.get("mything").add(frame);
}
```

And similar for image loading.

```
Image image = new Image(image_url);
image.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        // image is ready to be used.
    }
});
// attach to DOM to initiate loading of the image
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what they're asking for - the iframe will begin loading no later than when it is attached, and the image will start loading instantly, even if you don't attach it (and if it finishes loading before attach, you'll never get the handler called...). The question as written is asking for a way to delay until the parent is _visible_, and it is possible to be non-visible in many ways while still being attached.

Comment: @ColinAlworth You are right. I'm very new to UI and some of the basic concepts are difficult to grasp, specially that there are not many GXT resources for beginners in this regard. I tried to make my widget (extending `Html`) to implement GXT's `LoadHandler` (not GWT's) and register the widget in its constructor with `addHandler(this, Type<...>)`. Then invoke `fireEvent()` with `LoadEvent` in the presenter when the dialogue is about to be shown, but the implementation of `onLoad(LoadEvent<...>)` in the widget never gets called. Am I on a wrong path?

Comment: The GWT `LoadEvent` means "the DOM element for this widget has caused a native LOAD event", while the GXT `LoadEvent<C, M>` means "Data of type `M` for this loader has become available, from config `C`". Neither is what you want. Instead, you may want to look at the `AttachEvent` (then remove the handler when done), or perhaps watch for the dialog's `ShowEvent`, fired every time the dialog is shown on the screen (consider also `BeforeShowEvent`, which permits you to change your mind and not show it).